# Update one of many shapes in powerpoint slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to update one of many shapes in a powerpoint slide with a copied range from excel sheet with vba in excel. Though I am able to select the shape, I am not able to paste in to it. Below code is executing correct.

```
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Table 4").Select
```

But the below code gives "Object doesn't support this property/method" error.

```
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Table 4").Paste
```

The Table 4 is already existing in the slide, I need to update it with new data so will I need to delete Table 4 and then regenerate it?

Answer (score 1):

> > The Table 4 is already existing in the slide, I need to update it with new data so will I need to delete Table 4 and then regenerate it?

Either delete and regenerate, or replace the data in the existing table with the new data.

If you create a new table, you'll probably have to write a lot of code to pick up the z-order and formatting from the original table and apply it to the new one. Changing the data in the existing table will generally be a lot simpler.

By the way, this part:

```
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Table 4").Select
```

is not the best way to go about it. Never select anything if it's not absolutely necessary, and in this case it's not.

Instead:

```
With PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Table 4")
   ' do stuff
End With
```

or

```
Dim oTbl as Object
Set oTbl = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Table 4")
With oTbl
   ' do stuff
End With
```